# Using Python, how can we directly get measurements of facial features?

Tags: python, computer-vision, facial-identification

Are there any libraries/packages in Python which help detect landmarks from facial images and then compute facial measurements like the distance between the eyes, eyebrow length, lip thickness...?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a discussion forum, and requests for library recommendations are off topic here. We deal in objective problems; typically, problems to do with actual existing code that you have already written.

Comment: See https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/face_mesh